# How to add job in Subsystem in as400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to create one subsystem and run a job in this subsystem.

1. Creating Subsystem (SBS):

   ```
   CRTSBSD SBSD(MYSBS) POOLS((2 *BASE)) MAXJOBS(2) TEXT('DEMO SBS')
   ```
2. Create JOBQ:

   ```
   CRTJOBQ JOBQ(MYJOBQ) TEXT('JOBQ')
   ```
3. Add JOBQ entry in subsystem

   ```
   ADDJOBQE SBSD(MYSBS) JOBQ(MYJOBQ) SEQNBR(1)
   ```
4. Submit PWI job in this JOBQ

   ```
   SBMJOB CMD(JAVA CLASS('myprogram.jar') PARM(true) OUTPUT(*NONE)) JOBQ(MYJOBQ) JOB(MYJOB)
   ```
5. Start Subsystem

   ```
   STRSBS SBSD(MYSBS)
   ```

Here my aim is to create a subsystem and assign this "MYJOB" to "MYSBS".
For this I thought to create a JOBQ and give that JOBQ to the Subsystem

I don't know how to run this job in "MYSBS" subsystem.

Comment: What is happening? Where is the job running? Is there another jobq named `MYJOBQ` higher in the library list? Can you see the job in the jobq before the subsystem is started? Is there a job log?

Comment: When I start subsystem at last step, then subsystem is getting started but I can't see job running in this subsystem.

Comment: When I run WRKJOBQ JOBQ(MYJOBQ) then job is not getting disapled

Comment: start sbs before submiting job.

Comment: Starting subsystem first should not be necessary, jobs should sit in the jobq until a subsystem is available to process them. Try WRKJOBQ before the subsystem is started, and after the job is submitted. Does the job appear. Alternately, place the jobq on hold `HLDJOBQ JOBQ(MYJOBQ)` then submit the job. does the job appear in the jobq?

Comment: It could be that the job is running and finishing before you have a chance to look at it.

Comment: I had created class and added for this job and added routing entry. Problem Solved

Comment: @markmurphy. Than you for your help

Comment: @AnandDhage can you show how you added the class please?

Comment: Ok, you are missing a piece of the subsystem, the routing entries, thus the subsystem does not know what to do with the request messages coming in on the job queue. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76708585/2296441 for more info.